# How can I stop an event listener from slowing down my canvas animation?

Tags: javascript, canvas, event-listener

I am working on a canvas animation and I just started adding event listeners. Unfortunately, when I added a listener to track the location of the cursor, the animation slows down significantly every time I move the mouse. If I click, it stops completely. I'm guessing it's too much to process, so is there a way to improve the run time of the animation? Would this work with Web Workers?

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
//Variables for the blue ball
var bx = Math.random() * innerWidth;
var by = Math.random() * innerHeight;
var bbdx = 1;
var bbdy = 1;
var bRadius = 12;
//Variables for the red balls
var rx = Math.random() * innerWidth;
var ry = Math.random() * innerHeight;
var rrdx = 1;
var rrdy = 1;
var rRadius = 12;
//Mouse coordinate object
var mouse = {
  x: undefined,
  y: undefined
}

function bCircle() {
  c.beginPath();
  c.arc(bx, by, bRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  c.strokeStyle = "white";
  c.stroke();
  c.fillStyle = "cornflowerblue";
  c.fill();
  c.closePath();

  //Ball bouncing Conditional
}

function rCircle() {
  c.beginPath();
  c.arc(rx, ry, rRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  c.strokeStyle = "pink";
  c.stroke();
  c.fillStyle = "red";
  c.fill();
  c.closePath();
  //Ball Bouncing Conditional
}

//Interactivity function
function bClick() {
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
    mouse.x = event.x;
    mouse.y = event.y;
    console.log(mouse);
  });
}

function draw() {
  c.clearRect(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight);
  bCircle();
  rCircle();

  //bCircle Conditional
  if (bx + bRadius > innerWidth || bx - bRadius < 0) {
    bbdx = -bbdx;
  }
  //Conditional to mall the ball bounce up and down
  if (by + bRadius > innerHeight || by - bRadius < 0) {
    bbdy = -bbdy;
  }
  //Add 1 to x continously for it to move
  bx += bbdx;
  //Add 1 constantly to y for it to move up and down also
  by += bbdy;

  //rCircle Conditional
  if (rx + rRadius > innerWidth || rx - rRadius < 0) {
    rrdx = -rrdx;
  }
  if (ry + rRadius > innerHeight || ry - rRadius < 0) {
    rrdy = -rrdy;
  }
  rx += rrdx;
  ry += rrdy;

  bClick();
}

setInterval(function() {
  draw();
}, 8);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Tap-Tap</title>

  <style type="text/css">
    canvas {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    
    body {
      margin: 0;
      background-color: black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas></canvas>

  <script src="ball.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Pointy explains why this is having major problems in their answer, but as far as animation in general, you really should be using `requestAnimationFrame` for this.

Comment: I tried requestAnimationFrame before moving to setInterval. For some reason I had a bad time trying to run two animations at once. Will using setInterval have repercussions in the long run?

Comment: `setInterval` is subject to several issues that will degrade performance. First off, 8 is pretty aggressive, I think 4 is as fast as you can make it. Any interruption to the OS will cause that 8 to slow down temporarily and make your animation seem jumpy. Any change to the focus of the tab that the animation is running in will have the same effect, and may completely stop the animation causing a strange reversion when focus is obtained. Further, any change to the page which causes the page to be redrawn will also come prior to the interval firing and can cause very bad flickering.

Comment: You should change the call to setInterval instead to just `draw()`. Also, at this time simply call `bclick()` once. Then, at the end of the `draw` function, use `window.requestAnimationFrame(draw)`. And that is it.

Comment: It actually worked! Thanks for the information and extra help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding that "mousemove" event handler reduntantly on each call to `draw()`. The `.addEventListener()` API does *not* remove prior handlers already added.  After a little while there'll be hundreds of them and the browser will call each and every one.

Call `bClick()` once outside the timer handler. Also that `console.log()` call in the "mousemove" handler doesn't help performance.

Comment: The console log wont really effect performance from my observations, but having 120 mouse handlers added per second will.

Comment: I've actually noticed that, at least w chrome, having console.logs inside rapidly fired events significantly slows things down.

Comment: @TravisJ yes modern browsers seem to do `console.log()` work in a separate thread, particularly Chrome, which causes its own set of issues. It certainly won't *help* performance however.

Comment: Yeah, I see it was being called every time the animation was being called instead of just when I moved the mouse. I took the bclick() function of the draw() function and now it doesn't slow down.

Comment: I agree, there is no way to increase performance by using `console.log` :P If only that were a thing!